# Dynamics 365 OData filter data from a ComplexType

Tags: java, odata, microsoft-dynamics, restful-url, dynamics-365

**My goal is to create an OData query that just get the `"Value": 100000000,` data for the last entry in the Options array**. I am required to just send the `Value` field for the last Option in my response data before Java picks up the response and does some processing. I am not allowed to send the entire response to Java.

I'm trying to parse data from [Global Option Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt788314%28v%3Dcrm.8%29#retrieve-metadata-items-by-metadataid). I've having issues parsing the [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/optionmetadata?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) ComplexType and only able to get at the Options level so far in my current query.

`https://myorg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/GlobalOptionSetDefinitions(06d1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OptionSetMetadata`

Current sample response is below. Since Options is a ComplexType, I've not found any docs or guidance that points me in the right direction on how to do this. If I can get this OData query working in the way I want I can finally implement my scenario in Java.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://myorg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#GlobalOptionSetDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OptionSetMetadata/$entity",
    "ParentOptionSetName": null,
    "IsCustomOptionSet": true,
    "IsGlobal": true,
    "IsManaged": false,
    "Name": "new_customoptionset",
    "ExternalTypeName": "",
    "OptionSetType": "Picklist",
    "IntroducedVersion": "1.0",
    "MetadataId": "06d1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
    "HasChanged": null,
    "Options": [
        {
            "Value": 100000000,
            "Color": "#0000ff",
            "IsManaged": false,
            "ExternalValue": "",
            "ParentValues": [],
            "MetadataId": null,
            "HasChanged": null,
            "Label": {
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "Label": "a",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033,
                        "IsManaged": false,
                        "MetadataId": "09d1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                        "HasChanged": null
                    }
                ],
                "UserLocalizedLabel": {
                    "Label": "a",
                    "LanguageCode": 1033,
                    "IsManaged": false,
                    "MetadataId": "09d1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                    "HasChanged": null
                }
            },
            "Description": {
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "Label": "",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033,
                        "IsManaged": false,
                        "MetadataId": "0bd1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                        "HasChanged": null
                    }
                ],
                "UserLocalizedLabel": {
                    "Label": "",
                    "LanguageCode": 1033,
                    "IsManaged": false,
                    "MetadataId": "0bd1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                    "HasChanged": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Value": 100000001,
            "Color": "#0000ff",
            "IsManaged": false,
            "ExternalValue": "",
            "ParentValues": [],
            "MetadataId": null,
            "HasChanged": null,
            "Label": {
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "Label": "b",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033,
                        "IsManaged": false,
                        "MetadataId": "0cd1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                        "HasChanged": null
                    }
                ],
                "UserLocalizedLabel": {
                    "Label": "b",
                    "LanguageCode": 1033,
                    "IsManaged": false,
                    "MetadataId": "0cd1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                    "HasChanged": null
                }
            },
            "Description": {
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "Label": "",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033,
                        "IsManaged": false,
                        "MetadataId": "0ed1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                        "HasChanged": null
                    }
                ],
                "UserLocalizedLabel": {
                    "Label": "",
                    "LanguageCode": 1033,
                    "IsManaged": false,
                    "MetadataId": "0ed1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                    "HasChanged": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Value": 100000002,
            "Color": "#0000ff",
            "IsManaged": false,
            "ExternalValue": "",
            "ParentValues": [],
            "MetadataId": null,
            "HasChanged": null,
            "Label": {
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "Label": "c",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033,
                        "IsManaged": false,
                        "MetadataId": "0fd1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                        "HasChanged": null
                    }
                ],
                "UserLocalizedLabel": {
                    "Label": "c",
                    "LanguageCode": 1033,
                    "IsManaged": false,
                    "MetadataId": "0fd1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                    "HasChanged": null
                }
            },
            "Description": {
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "Label": "",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033,
                        "IsManaged": false,
                        "MetadataId": "11d1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                        "HasChanged": null
                    }
                ],
                "UserLocalizedLabel": {
                    "Label": "",
                    "LanguageCode": 1033,
                    "IsManaged": false,
                    "MetadataId": "11d1a507-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                    "HasChanged": null
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "Description": {
        "LocalizedLabels": [
            {
                "Label": "",
                "LanguageCode": 1033,
                "IsManaged": false,
                "MetadataId": "83ca9f0d-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                "HasChanged": null
            }
        ],
        "UserLocalizedLabel": {
            "Label": "",
            "LanguageCode": 1033,
            "IsManaged": false,
            "MetadataId": "83ca9f0d-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
            "HasChanged": null
        }
    },
    "DisplayName": {
        "LocalizedLabels": [
            {
                "Label": "MyCustom Option Set",
                "LanguageCode": 1033,
                "IsManaged": false,
                "MetadataId": "82ca9f0d-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
                "HasChanged": null
            }
        ],
        "UserLocalizedLabel": {
            "Label": "MyCustom Option Set",
            "LanguageCode": 1033,
            "IsManaged": false,
            "MetadataId": "82ca9f0d-4d57-e911-a82a-000d3a1d5203",
            "HasChanged": null
        }
    },
    "IsCustomizable": {
        "Value": true,
        "CanBeChanged": true,
        "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "iscustomizable"
    }
}
```

I am able to filter the JSON in Java, but again I'd prefer to filter in OData first to get this single `Value` field.

```
try {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://myorg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/GlobalOptionSetDefinitions%28" +
                    optionSetGuidString +
                    "%29/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OptionSetMetadata/Options")
            .get()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String dataReturnedFromGetOptions = response.body().string();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(dataReturnedFromGetOptions);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("value");
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(jsonArray.length() - 1);
    previousValue = jsonObject.getInt("Value");
}
catch (IOException e) { }
```

Comment: what is the exactly problem you have? if you get the response you just need to parse it. Options is just an array of objects

Comment: I want to create an OData query that gives me a response just get the `Value` field and it's data within the options array.

Comment: @Guido what recommendations do you have for parsing a JSON response in Java?

Comment: @GregDegruy check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: @GuidoPreite thanks I was able to implement this here https://github.com/gregdegruy/dynamics-rest-with-adal/blob/master/dynamicscrmapi/src/main/java/Main.java I will leave this question unanswered as ideally I'd still like to filter the data as much as I can before Java picks up the rest of the work.